# Maxmum value between two points on the bar register in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am looking to determine the high, say for example between 20 bars ago and 40 bars ago.....how do I do that? Must be easy, but I am at a loss :). Cant get it from the other similar examples here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float hh = high[20]

for i = 21 to 40
    if high[i] > hh
        hh := high[i]
```